# i18n.changeLanguage is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-i18next

This is my code.

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function Page() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = lng => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('de')}>de</button>
        <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>en</button>
      </div>
      <div>{t('test')}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
      <Page />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

when I click on the `de en` button. I get this error. TypeError: i18n.changeLanguage is not a function.How to fix?

Comment: Hi, did you try ```import i18n from 'i18next';```?

Comment: Can you share your `i18n.js` file (a file with i18n config)?

Comment: @rcoro Why do I need import i18n from'i18next ' ?

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Where is i18n config located?

Answer (score 26):

Looks like you haven't configured `i18next`.

You will need to create a file `i18n.js` containing the following content:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';


i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    }
  });
export default i18n;
```

Then import it in your `index.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from './App';

import './i18n';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[source](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks)

Comment: It seems I did everything right but it doesn't work.https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snow-rsf86

Comment: It is working, the function `changeLanguage ` is now available and you can call it.

Comment: I do not understand.I showed my broken code.Are you saying that it works? can show on my code how should i use changeLanguage ?

Comment: I get a warning .i18next: languageChanged ru ..i18next::translator: missingKey ru translation test test .

Comment: That's because you need to add a translation file, or set up your backend so that it provides you with the translation, check this: https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 5):

I had same error. Unfortunately the i18n documentation is not very good.

We need to create the i18n [provider](https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18nextprovider) (I18nextProvider) and pass it an i18n object after calling the `init` function. Of course, we have to wrap our App in I18nextProvider

**i18n.js**

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import en from './en.json';
import de from './de.json';

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: en,
      },
      de: {
        translation: de,
      },
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation, I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './i18n';

function Page() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = lng => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('de')}>de</button>
        <button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>en</button>
      </div>
      <div>{t('test')}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Page />
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: i had the same error and found myself here. 
The solution for me: I accidentally commented out the import in index.js and it didn't work. 

Now it's working without the Provider and without the export default. 
just had to import the i18n.js for it's side-effects in index.js.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only)

from the i18next docs:
"You will only need to use the provider if you need to support multiple i18next instances "
https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18nextprovider#when-to-use

Answer (score 4):

a) move changeLanguage like in the code above - but also import i18n from '../i18n'; or where you defined your i18n instance.

```
import i18n from 'i18n';

// define the function outside of component scope
const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
};
```

b) Or following steps:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function Page() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const toggle = lng => i18n.changeLanguage(lng); 
  if (this.props.event){

   return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <button onClick={() => toggle(this.props.event)}>de</button>
        <button onClick={() => toggle(this.props.event)}>en</button>
      </div>
      <div>{t('test')}</div>
    </div>
   );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was not a config problem. What you need to do was to add

```js
import "./util/i18n";
```

in your App.tsx and rebuild your project, ie run `npm run start` again.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use inside your onClick input events

```js
() => changeLanguage('en').bind(this)
```

This could resolve your problem.